# How to use indexes in sql database?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have one table that contains 3 columns. Primary id, uuid, date(last login). When users are loging in I run query to database to check if user with this uuid exists. This table should work super fast for ~5mln users. How to make query on table like that faster? Will it help if I add another column for ex. country, and use it as a index?

Comment: Why are you asking about `country`?  What does that have to do with the data?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: "Will it help if I add another column for ex. country," only if you run a query based on that field. If you're checking for the existence of a uuid then another field is not really relevant

Comment: What I meant was if I add column for country and every time I do query for uuid I pass also country - Would it speed things up? I'm new to web development and database related topics. Which DBMS? Currently I'm testing mysql and postgre next to eachother to check what would be better in my case.

Comment: since the uuid must already be unique I don't think adding another column into the where clause would achieve anything. You're already looking for one specific value. Restricting it by another value which might be in multiple rows won't make that any faster. BTW why is uuid not your primary key?

Comment: @ADyson From what I read on the internet that using uuid as a primary key have its disadventages for example speed of insert. Reference: https://medium.com/@Mareks_082/auto-increment-keys-vs-uuid-a74d81f7476a But I'm new to the topic and still wondering about if trading a little speed for easier replication and smaller database is worth it.

Comment: well, it won't be as fast as using an int, now. Look at it the other way round, then. Do you need the uuid actually? Does it come from somewhere else in order to match the user with some other data source? Or can you exist with just the integer primary key?

Comment: UUID is actually fb user id connected with my fb app. So it actually is necessary.

Comment: Ok well in that case your current design makes sense. Always good to make sure, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check a particular `uuid`, then you want an index on that column:

```
create index idx_table_uuid on table(uuid);
```

This should be fast enough for your purposes.